# Python taking away time

Tags: python, time

I am trying to take away one time to the other to find out how long the users account will be locked for but instead of getting this:

```
0:23:48:55
```

I get this:

```
21 days , 23:48:55
```

I am using this method:

```
end_time = accounts[user].get("today")
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
total_time =(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d:%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%d:%H:%M:%S'))
print(total_time)
```

The end_time has tomorrows date in it which is:

```
23:14:29:21
```

so taking the current time away should give:

```
0:23:48:21
```

but not 21 days.
Any ideas why this is doing that and how to fix this

Comment: What is the value in `accounts[user].get("today")`?

Comment: 23:14:29:21  or tomorrows date at 2:29 pm and 21 seconds

Comment: Print the value of `start_time`; it isn't what you think.

Comment: now it is fixed thanks for noticing m8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your start_time because `.time()` remove the value of the day.

```
end_time = "23:14:29:21"
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
total_time =(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d:%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%d:%H:%M:%S'))
print(total_time)
```

Comment: You have to concatenate the variable to make it a single string, for exemple : `showerror(f"This account was locked, Please contact the admin to unlock your account.\n It will get unlocked in {8}")`

Comment: done something like this error.showerror("This account was locked","Please contact the admin to unlock your account.\n It will get unlocked in %s" % total_time) but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would Be More Like This, The `.time()` Function Removes The Value Of The Day (Instead Of Counting The Number Of Days (Like 0,1))

```
#Fixed Code
end_time = "23:14:29:21"
start_time = time.strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
total_time =(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%d:%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%d:%H:%M:%S'))
print(total_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

changed

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
```

to

```
start_time = time.strftime("%d:%H:%M:%S")
```